# Watching for File renaming in vscode extension

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

Is there a way to watch file name changes in vscode extensions. I am looking to know the old name -> new name for a file rename or when a user saves a file that was previously unsaved (Untitled-1 -> someName.txt for example).

I noticed that there is a FileSystemWatcher but it only seems to track onDidChange, onDidCreate and onDidDelete and each of those callbacks only passes a single URI.

Is there some better way to do this?

Comment: Did you find the answer?

Answer (score 2):

Create a FileSystemWatcher with the desired glob path that is relevant to you

```
var watcher = vscode.workspace.createFileSystemWatcher("**/*.ts"); //glob search string
watcher.ignoreChangeEvents = false;

watcher.onDidChange(() => {
 vscode.window.showInformationMessage("change applied!"); 
});
```

Taken from - [Using FileSystemWatcher in Typescript (Visual Studio Code extension)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34230714/using-filesystemwatcher-in-typescript-visual-studio-code-extension)

Answer (score 0):

As of VS Code 1.29, a file rename api is tracked [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/43768).

You can try this today using the [proposed APIs](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/wiki/Extension-API-process):

```
export namespace workspace {
    export const onWillRenameFile: Event<FileWillRenameEvent>;
    export const onDidRenameFile: Event<FileRenameEvent>;
}
```